# How to rewrite/change url using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess

I know this has already been answered, but mine is somehow special.

Firstly, my site is not a PHP site (it's an XHTML site).

So, can someone teach me how to rewrite url like this:

```
mysite.com/forum2_theme_CATEGORY-ID.xhtml?n=PAGE-ID&tema=TOPIC-ID
```

To something like:

```
mysite.com/forum2/CATEGORY-ID/TOPIC-ID/PAGE-ID
```

Please note that my site is not a PHP site, it's just an XHTML site.

I will be happy if I can get a suitable solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Use an online generator for htaccess rules: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: How are you handling requests with query strings right now? (Side question: how are you making a forum if you aren't using a server side language to access a DB?)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get your hands a bit dirty with Apache mod_rewrite. There's lots of good tutorials for beginners:

http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

you also might be able to find an existing examples of similar rewrite rules to yours as your case is pretty standard

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the url you can use:
`window.history.pushState("", "", '/newpage');`
But it's not the proper  way to build a website.

I don't understand how are you creating a forum without using any server site language like PHP. I suggest to use a framework like ZendFramework(PHP), Spring(Java), ExpressJS, etc. Instead of modifying the mod_rewrite.